# mysql LAST_INSERT_ID() is causing some SQL problems when passing back value retrieved

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I need some help figuring out why the following scenario does not work.  I'm trying to retrieve a value from the last updated ID in mysql, then pass that value via javascript over to an ajax call which calls a .php page, which also calls another function "ZEND_emaiL" in a different php page.

In the very first php page that retrieves the id from mysql LAST_INSERT_ID(), if I hard code the value "100" it works, but if I use the value returned from LAST_INSERT_ID() it causes a failure.

Here's the php code for the LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
$sql='SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();';
$last_updated_id = $db->get_var( $sql );
$last_updated_id = $last_updated_id+0;//make int
echo $last_updated_id; //send output back to the ajax call
var_dump($last_updated_id); ------------->RETURNS **int 149**
```

if I send back a hard coded "100" like this: `echo 100;` then it works.

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help in advance.

The following are values retrieved from the php page that contains the ZEND_email() function.  I grabbed these for debugging purposes hoping it would help.

RETURN VALUES for Hard Coded:

```
var_dump($n_id);---------->Returns **int 100**
var_dump($sqlresult);----->Returns **resource 24**
var_dump($row);----------->Returns **array of data to parse through**
```

RETURN VALUES FOR Passed in Variable (Fails):

```
function ZEND_email($to, $from="", $subject="", $msg="", $notif_id='', $root_dir="")
{
var_dump($notif_id);---------------------->RETURNS **string '100'**
$notif_id = $notif_id+0;//convert to int
var_dump($notif_id);---------------------->RETURNS **int 100**

$n_id = $notif_id;      
$xsql = $sql_str->SQL_SELECT_all_notif_attachments($account_id, $n_id);

$sqlresult=mysql_query($xsql);
$row=mysql_fetch_row($sqlresult);

var_dump($n_id);---------------->RETURNS **int 100**
var_dump($sqlresult);----------->RETURNS **resource 24**
var_dump($row);----------------->RETURNS **boolean false**
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the code entirely, but you are aware that LAST_INSERT_ID() works only if the record was inserted in the same mySQL connection?

Comment: maybe dumb question, but in your ZNED_email where is the $sql_str object definied ? also can you explain what are you trying to do, and what exactly does not work.

Comment: You say `the last updated ID in mysql`. `last_insert_id()` is only valid for INSERT queries. Any other query type will result in undefined behavior. What is your DB abstraction later doing between the time you insert a layer and do the `SELECT last_insert_id()`?

Comment: That `//make int` line doesn't make much sense. If you `echo` the value it will be converted back to string anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to scrap this code...couldn't get it all to work with the feature for the app so we dropped it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you are aware that you could use `mysql_insert_id()` ? 
see http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php which would give you an INT value directly,

btw, to convert a variable to integer you can use:

```
$foo = (int) $bar
```

or

```
$foo = intval($bar);
```

or

```
$foo = settype($bar,'int');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from those code snippets. Better check what's going on on the client-side.
E.g. with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can both check the actual response data and step into the javascript code.